# Array of pointers to integers

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, pointers

I am trying to sort an array of pointers to integers (instead of the array of integers itself)

But when I try to initialize the array of pointers to the addresses of the integers in the integers array my program crashes.

```
int** pointerSort(int* arr, int size)
{

    int i;

    // allocate memory for result array and verify success of allocation
    int** res = (int**)malloc(size*sizeof(int*));
    if (res = NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory allocation failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // initialize pointers array with addresses
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        res[i] = &(arr[i]);

    // sort the array using merge sort algorithm
    mergeSort(res, size-1);

    return res;
}
```

my program crashes on `res[i] = &(arr[i]);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`if (res = NULL)` Here you're assigning `NULL` to `res`. 
You want to compare, not to assign, you should use `==`.

It's good to mention that the expression of the assignment returns the **assigned value**, in this case, it's `NULL`. 
In your code, `if` statement could be evaluated to `false`, even if `malloc` failed to allocate memory.

This is another good reason why we should compile with warnings!

Comment: And that's why you should compile with warnings.

Comment: +1, good warnings are a lot better than yoda conditions.  It's perfectly idiomatic to just use `if (!res)` in C, too.

Comment: @CarlNorum, lol "Yoda" conditions.  Yes, I totally agree that warnings are superior but IMO not leveraging Yoda conditions creates a subtle dependency on those warnings which maintainers might not respect (and there'd be nothing obvious to indicate that the code is "dependent" on those warnings).

Comment: + Maroun Congrats for your 10K RPs!

Answer (score 4):

As other answers indicate, the problem is your assignment used as a conditional:

```
if (res = NULL)
```

But here's a tip for avoiding this specific failure mode: put the literal on the left hand side:

```
if (NULL = res)
```

`NULL` (and other literals) are not legal lvalues, that is -- they're not legally assigned to, so your compiler will refuse to continue if you or a maintainer accidentally delete that critical second-equals character in the expression.

Comment: Change the coding style in if clause(if(NULL = res)) is helpful.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Because When you misspell the equal operator== as operator=, the compile will throw an error with if(NULL = res), but with if(res = NULL) (which is not what you mean), sometimes compiler do not even throw a warning. It is better you get an error if your code is not what you mean.

Comment: @lulyon You taught me a new concept, very nice, Thanks!